# duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 caused by separate pods (MobileVLCKit, box-ios-sdk)

Tags: ios, vlc, box

I am getting a strange error where it appears one pods information is being duplicated by the addition of a completely separate pod. For clarification I am running 'MobileVLCKit' and 'box-ios-sdk' cocoapods. Running either by itself works fine but when both are included in the Podfile I get 'ld: 253 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVF3P.png)

For those of you that want to install the MobileVLCKit to help and run into issues you can use this link to set it up https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=137065#p453804

Comment: I'm not familiar with either of these libraries, but these types of linker errors will occur if both frameworks include some other library, causing the symbols to be duplicated. By the looks of your screenshot, they are both including some version of the vlc library (videolan.org)

Comment: @Shackleford but the duplicate errors never directly mention the box-ios-sdk framework.And assuming you are correct do you know of a solution or work around if they are.